# How to average 1000+ regression coefficients?

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients

I am doing OLS regression on 1000's of stocks forward returns against a factor score. All the factor scores are the same model results for each stock at some point in time and vary between 1-5.

My original test was to just aggregate all the series and and regress the aggregate. I got a reasonable number but I'm thinking that idea might be flawed.

I don't think I can just take the mean of a list of coefficients so what is the best way to find the average slope? I read something about using the fisher transformation but wanted to confirm that fits what I am trying to do.

*EDIT May be worth mentioning that the distribution of all the regression coefficients is pretty normally distributed.

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Rather than average slopes, is there a reason you can't run a single regression model with a variable for stock?

Comment: @David I was to find the average relationship between a factor across all of the stocks.

Comment: @FransRodenburg Thanks! :) That's what I did at first if i'm reading your question right. I basically aggregated all the data into one series and ran a regression on over 1m points, and the output was reasonable but i'm questioning if that is the right way to do it. If I ran single regressions on individual stocks and the average of those is different than the regression on the aggregate, which one is a better representation.

Comment: In that case, yes, you can estimate the average effect size by averaging the estimations for each coefficient. The problem is that this "average effect" could turn out to be meaningless

Comment: @David Thanks! I appreciate the response. I got a coefficient of -.03 when I ran the aggregate regression and -.1 when I take the average. The distribution of all the regression coefficients is pretty normal.

Comment: What you did at first is correct approach. Maybe you need to adjust/modify the model. But averaging the estimates is bad approach.

Comment: @user158565 That's OK but you may en up in trouble because of lack of independence between stock returns

Comment: That is what I mean by "adjust/modify". If lack of independence, try to add random effects in the model.

Comment: @user158565 Thanks for the response,  I got a coefficient of -3%  when I ran the aggregate regression and -10% when I take the average. So at least they are both negative.